# Можно ли аргументом функции определить родительский класс, а в теле функции использовать один из дочерних?

Tags: c++, ооп, классы, наследование, полиморфизм

Есть класс ClassBase и 2 его дочерних ClassChild1, ClassChild2.
Нужно нечто подобное:

```
foo(ClassBase elem){
    // тут работать с объектом одного из дочерних
}
```

На ум приходят шаблоны, но не могу понять как реализовать это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, в таких случаях следует использовать передачу по ссылке, иначе вы столкнетесь со срезкой, если и когда вместо родительского объекта будете передавать дочерний.

Использовать-то дочерний класс можно, только надо использовать приведение `dynamic_cast`, если не хотите неприятностей. Только он обеспечивает безопасное приведение (или указывает, что оно невозможно).

```
void foo(ClassBase * elem)
{
    ...
    ChildClass1 * с = dynamic_cast<ChildClass1 *>(elem);
    if (c) {
        ...
```

Примерно так. При использовании ссылок надо перехватывать исключение `bad_cast`.

Этим ответ исчерпывается.

А теперь давайте просто подумаем — зачем? Если вы передаете в функцию родительский класс, значит, вы как бы заключаете контракт — при передаче такого объекта родительского класса все будет отлично работать. И если вы действительно передадите объект такого класса, то в нем же просто нет функциональности дочернего класса?

Скорее всего, вы просто "затыкаете" какую-то возникшую дыру, вместо того, чтобы пересмотреть саму конструкцию, проект. Применение такого приведения родителя к ребенку в большинстве случаев признак какой-то недодуманности. Просто подумайте, нет ли иного пути решения вашей проблемы.

Comment: Вероятно да, архитектурно я в чем-то ошибся. В моем случае, дочерние классы имею свои уникальные свойства, влияющие на дальнейшие вычисления. А вычислить нужно значение между двумя объектами (включая все дочерние) одним методом. Хотел один метод написать, чтобы не перегружать. В общем, буду думать, благодарю.

Comment: а может чуточку больше напишите о деталях проблемы? скорее всего функцию можно поместить в базовый класс и она будет использовать разные виртуальные функции, которые уже определяют наследники.

Comment: @KoVadim Есть родительский класс "Equipment" и дочерние "Cell", "NodeB", "User". Есть класс по типу Фабрика, который управляет взаимодействием и логикой работы "Network". В методах "Network" нужно посчитать расстояние (и не только) между любыми двумя объектами.
Хотя, сейчас появилась идея поместить эти параметры в отдельный класс и держать значение ссылкой, тогда можно по новому классу работать, не касаясь оборудования.

Comment: ну так координаты это свойство Equipment и координаты должны легко считаться на основе этого предположения. Если же какой то класс умеет как то странно изменять свои координаты, то пусть Equipment имеет виртуальную функцию для этого и дочерние классы могут переопределить под себя.

Comment: @KoVadim В том то и дело. Это несложная задача, просто я т*плю. В классе "Network" методы "CalculateDistance(Cell &cell, Ue &ue)", "CalculateDistance(Cell &cell, Cell &cell)", "CalculateDistance(Ue &ue, Ue &ue)" . Но я вот сейчас понял, можно внутри "Equipment" сделать 2 метода "distanceToCell(Cell &cell)" и "distanceToUe(Ue &ue)". Хотелось бы, конечно, до одного метода сократить.

Comment: вводите новый базовый класс `Thing`, который содержит исключительно координаты и наследуете это чудо класс `Ue` (не понятно, что это такое) и класс Equipment  тоже от него. И все, задача решена

Comment: @KoVadim Класс координат у меня есть, с ними все нормально работает. Есть еще куча рассчетов, которые нужно проводить с не всегда одинаковыми параметрами UE(User Equipment) и Cell. Для этого тоже нужно выводить все в отдельные классы?

Comment: а этого я не знаю. пока мне недостаточно информации для понимания всей сложности задачи